# How can I globally access in app settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have some in app settings, all of which are very basic, and I am needing to access them throughout my entire app. I have it setup where those settings are saved to NSUserDefaults. My question is if the best way to access them is having to load from NSUserDefaults every time an instance of a class loads or if it's better to have it loaded once somewhere and somehow access that global data from everywhere. How could I go about doing the latter if that is the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults unless profiling data from Instruments suggests that it might be a problem. If there's a problem, then it could be time to consider caching.

NSUserDefaults already does cache for you though, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

Make a class LoadUserDefaults from NSObject.

Your header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoadUserDefaults : NSObject

//example variables
int score;

NSString username;


//etc...

-(void)loadUserDefaults;

@end
```

Now to your .m file:

```
#import "LoadUserDefaults.h"

@implementation LoadUserDefaults

-(void)loadUserDefaults{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    score = [defaults valueForKey:@"score"];

    username = [defaults valueForKey:@"username"];

    //etc.

}


@end
```

Next import your class everywhere you want to have access to your defaults:

```
#import "LoadUserDefaults"
```

After that load them somewhere:

```
LoadUserDefaults *loadDefaults = [[LoadUserDefaults alloc]init];

[loadDefaults loadUserDefaults];
```

Finally when you want to get your variables:

```
 LoadUserDefaults *loadDefaults = [[LoadUserDefaults alloc]init];

 int score = loadDefaults.score
```